# Pi 2 Raspian @ on keyboard not working

Tags: raspbian

I have a Pi 2 running Raspian. It has USB keyboard attached.
I have to use "shift +" to get @ sign.

How can I get the @ on the keyboard to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably have it set to a different country than you are used to. Execute the following in the command line:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

Then, find where it says `XKBLAYOUT=”gb”` and change the gb (or anything else) to the two letter code for your country.

If you are from the US, it should read like so:

```
XKBLAYOUT=”us”
```

Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: No problem, I find that easier than going into the config and looking for it there. @Reddirt

Answer (score 2):

You need to reconfigure your keyboard layout. Use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

To reconfigure it and follow instructions on screen. To use standard layout check us_US.UTF-8 locales.